# Download data from Illumina BaseSpace

Tags: command-line, bioinformatics

I want to be able to download data from BaseSpace in fastq-format. I know that you can download data through the browser, but I would like to do this using the Linux-command line.

I'm already looking into creating an API, but I don't have any experience with that whatsoever...

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you post how do you do it with the browser? is there any url to the archive in fastaq format? If so you could try wget <url-to-fastaq-file>

Comment: @Llopis, the way to do it through the browser is described in [this link](https://support.basespace.illumina.com/knowledgebase/articles/145775-download-fastq-files-from-a-project-using-the-file). I know I can use `wget` to download things. I already tried this method, but it doesn't work

Comment: Then you have [this](https://developer.basespace.illumina.com/) option and build your own script, they already have [an API](https://developer.basespace.illumina.com/docs/content/documentation/rest-api/api-reference). [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/basespace-developers/A$20more$20gentle$20introduction$20to$20the$20python$20API/basespace-developers/jj7-IPXDgCY/hj8JYFMhwscJ) seems particular interesting

Comment: I was afraid that would be the only option. Thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe someone has already created what you want see the edit on my previous comment. Good luck. If you find something (or create your own script) could you answer your own question for other people with the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [basemount](https://basemount.basespace.illumina.com/) --a tool developed by Illumina-- that streamline what you want to do. With basemount I can mount my BaseSpace Sequence Hub within my linux machine.

For instance, when I run:

```
mkdir BaseSpace    
basemount BaseSpace
```

I get a folder (`BaseSpace`) with the same directory structure of the one shown in the website of my BaseSpace account. Then, to copy files from BaseSpace to my local machine, I just do:

```
cp BaseSpace/path/to/file/fileName /path/in/local/machine/
```

Please, look at the [documentation](https://basemount.basespace.illumina.com/) for how to install `basemount` and  log-in into your BaseSpace account.

Comment: thanks for your answer. We have already implemented this method in the last few months

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this same thing using the API, but the script here seems to be a user-friendly wrapper for the same thing:

https://github.com/nh13/basespace-invaders

It requires credentials that you receive when you choose to "Create New Application" on https://developer.basespace.illumina.com/; this is not at all difficult and the README page for the above github has some instructions.